# Replacing getopts.pl with Getopt::Std

Tags: perl, cygwin

I am using Cygwin version 2.10.0 with perl 5.26.0. I need to change `getopts.pl` to `Getopt::Std` but what to do with `&Getopts('F:f:');` line then?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
require "getopts.pl" ;

# Perl script to take particle data and
# plot using (in this case) GMT to 
# produce a postscript file of specified size.
# Assumption is that this is a frame for a movie
# and hence that time information is meaningful

&Getopts('F:f:');
# Options:   -f: Filename for input data
# Options:   -F: Filename (root) for output data

# default values for parameters if not specified
if($opt_F eq "") {
  $opt_F = "ascii-conversion";
}

# Read the particle file ...   Assume 2D !! 
open(PAR,"< $opt_f") || die "File not found $opt_f\n";
open(OUT,"> $opt_F") || die "File not found $opt_F\n";
# open(OUT,">$name") || die "Cannot open file $name : $!\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html): You should be able to just replace

```
require "getopts.pl";
&Getopts('F:f:');
```

with

```
use Getopt::Std;
getopts('F:f:');
```

If you also `use warnings;` and `use strict;` (as is generally recommended), you'll need to declare the variables beforehand with `our ($opt_F, $opt_f);`. Alternatively, you can use a hash:

```
getopts('F:f:', \my %opts);
$opts{f} # instead of $opt_f
$opts{F} # instead of $opt_F
```

Comment: Thank you so much..first part worked. no needed to use declaration of variables.